# Dependent subquery with IN clause

Tags: mysql, performance

I have one update query which uses a subquery in its IN clause. The subquery only returns one row. For example:

```
UPDATE users SET a = a * 2 WHERE id IN (SELECT id from txns WHERE txnid = 'abc');
```

The `users` table has millions of rows, and hence the `explain` tells me that this is really inefficient as the subquery is dependent. But when I change `IN` to `=` in above clause, the performance increases and explain also doesn't say this subquery as 'dependent'.

explain output:

```
+----+--------------------+----------------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+--------+------------------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table                | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref   | rows   | Extra                              |
+----+--------------------+----------------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+--------+------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | users                | index | NULL          | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL  | 974115 | Using where                        |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | txns                 | ref   | txnid2        | txnid2  | 258     | const |      1 | Using index condition; Using where |
+----+--------------------+----------------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+--------+------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)


+----+-------------+----------------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+-----------------------+
| id | select_type | table                | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra                 |
+----+-------------+----------------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+-----------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | users                | range | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | const |    1 | Using where           |
|  2 | SUBQUERY    | txns                 | ref   | txnid2        | txnid2  | 258     | const |    1 | Using index condition |
+----+-------------+----------------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+-----------------------+
```

Could someone explain what exactly is happening here ?

Comment: And which version of MySQL?

Comment: Could you post the EXPLAIN for boh situation?I suspect in the first case you get an index scan where in the second you get an index seek.Mysql is notoriously bad with IN subqueries.

Comment: Also, how many rows are affected by the second query, compared with the first query?

Answer (score 0):

`IN ( SELECT ... )` is inefficiently optimized.  Avoid it.

`= ( SELECT ... )` -- the subquery will be evaluated once, hence more efficient.  But you really need a correlated subquery ("dependent").

"Multi-table UPDATE" is even more efficient because it will use a JOIN.  Something like:

```
UPDATE   users
    JOIN txns ON txns.id = users.id
    SET users.a = users.a * 2
    WHERE txns.txnid = 'abc';
```